# Integrating derivative ($f$ of bounded variation)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, and define $ν(x)=TV(f_{[a,x]}) ∀x∈[a,b]$,

I want to show: $\int_a^b|f'|= TV(f)$ iff $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$.

My attempts:

I've shown $|f'|\leq v'$ a.e. on $[a,b]$ and infered that $\int_a^b|f'|\leq TV(f)$.

Comment: What's your definition of $\int_a^b|f'|$, explicitly in terms of say supremums or infimums or what-not?

Comment: The notes at the end of Chapter 20 "Differentiation" in Neal L. Carothers *Real Analysis* refer to Wheeden, R. L. and Zygmund, A. [1977] *Measure and Integral* for a proof that $v'(x) = |f'(x)|$ a.e. when $f \in BV[a,b]$.

Comment: Would you like to give a hint?@kahen